# Como criar subdomínios automáticos a partir de um formulário?

Tags: subdomínio

Estou desenvolvimento um sistema grande, que já atende quase 30 empresas no estado e mais algumas estão pra aderir.

O sistema é acessado pelas empresas à partir dessa url:

- meudomínio.com.br/**empresa1**
- meudomínio.com.br/**empresa2**
- meudomínio.com.br/**empresa3**

Gostaria de saber como fazer o "automatic subdomain" que é tipo isso aqui:

[image: Subdomínio automático por formulário]

Informo o nome da empresa e ela passa a acessar o sistema a partir de **empresa1.meudomínio.com.br**

Comment: Isso é uma configuração do Apache. Não vejo como um sistema que roda sob o próprio Apache poderia alterar uma configuração dele.
Minha sugestão seria de manter os domínios salvos em algum banco e usar uma cron para buscar os domínios criados e criá-los nas configurações do Apache.

Comment: Você pode confirmar qual web server está usando? Como disse o @rodrigorigotti, o ideal seria agendar uma tarefa que altere as configurações do servidor, mas como fazer isso depende do servidor usado, (e dependendo do caso, também do sistema operacional).

Comment: Uso o cPanel, segue um ss das configurações do servidor: [link](http://prntscr.com/2tebso)

Comment: Antes precisa ter um banco de dados com a lista de subdomínios. Depois basta criar um **subdomínio coringa *.dominio.com.br** apontando para um arquivo testa_subdominio.php. Quando o usuário digitar meulogin.dominio.com.br, o servidor chama testa_subdominio.php que faz a conexão com o BD e carrega a página para o login "meulogin" ou erro 404, se o login não existir ou for inválido.

Comment: Se você estiver usando o cpanel, você pode utilizar essa biblioteca do cpanel que permite você criar subdomínios passando parâmetros com PHP. https://github.com/CpanelInc/xmlapi-php

Answer (score 3):

Permitindo que o apache crie pastas... dos dinâmicos esse é o melhor pois os paths internos são corrigidos sozinhos, sem impacto ao php por exemplo...
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html#simple

Mas ja utilizei o metodo do arquivo de texto, não tinha interface grafica, para administrar, mas o cliente podia subir um arquivo texto no ftp no qual ele colocava o subdominio e a pasta raiz e o apache subia o site no ato, conforme o site da apache:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower

# define the map file
RewriteMap vhost txt:/www/conf/vhost.map

# deal with aliases as above
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/icons/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cgi-bin/
RewriteCond ${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}} ^(.+)$
# this does the file-based remap
RewriteCond ${vhost:%1} ^(/.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ %1/docs/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cgi-bin/
RewriteCond ${lowercase:%{SERVER_NAME}} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond ${vhost:%1} ^(/.*)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ %1/cgi-bin/$1
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html#xtra-conf

Comment: Valeu @BrenoZan. Só uma dúvida com isso: esse arquivo map "vhost.mp" eu tenho que criar? Qual o modelo do arquivo?

Comment: sim vocÊ que cria... na pratica também pode usar mdb ou mysql (NÃO USE!), só precisa atender as compatibilidades de mapa do rewrite
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbm. 
Eu realmente sugiro que use o simple.. os outros dão uma senhoda dor de cabeça com os paths e questões de segurança das aplicações dentro deles..